# minimize with positive constraints returns zero parameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am using `scipy.optimize.minimize` to minimize a function with `l2` norm constraints and non-negative constraints on the computed parameters (some related links [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631192/element-wise-constraints-in-scipy-optimize-minimize), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767657/how-do-i-use-a-minimization-function-in-scipy-with-constraints), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50693445/logistic-regression-with-weights-constraintsnon-nagetive-desceding-order)). More specifically, I have tried

```
con = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x}, {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.dot(x.T, x) - 1})
```

or

```
con = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.dot(x.T, x) - 1}
bounds = [(0., None)] * n_features
```

with method `SLSQP`. The the accuracy of the algorithm is fine If the positive constraint is not used. However, when the positive constraint is used, most of the computed parameters `x` became zero and the algorithm returns low accuracy. To avoid this situation, I have tried different initializations, e.g., non-negative `x0` with `l2` norm equal to 1, `x0` values close to zero, `x0` values close to 1 but didin't help. Any suggestions to improve the functionality of the algorithm are highly appreciated.

**EDIT**: A running example can be found [here](https://github.com/thothxp/nnLR-scipy).

Comment: (1) A bound is better than a constraint. (2) This is nonconvex. See if a different starting point helps.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen thanks for the interest. Please let me share my implementation. I have tried different initialization but without success. Is it possible to review my code? It is Logistic Regression.

Comment: I also tried to use `trust-constr` but I couldn't make it. The error `ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly` is returned. The same error is discussed [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/9146) but I couldn't understand it. It possible to cast some light on this too? Maybe another optimization method will work more efficiently.

Comment: The constraints for SLSQP and trust-constr are specified in a different format. This is easy to miss in the documentation. You also may want to provide some working code that can be executed and demonstrates the problem..

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen here is a [link](https://github.com/thothxp/nnLR-scipy) of the complete code.